# Memory density understanding

Tags: memory, ddr4

I am trying to understand DDR4 [datasheet](https://download.semiconductor.samsung.com/resources/product-guide/DDR4_Product_guide_May.18.pdf). All memory chips listed on page 3 have density equal to organization multiplication except 16Gb B-die and 32Gb A-die ones.

Let's pick K4A8G165WC. Chip have org. 512 millions of 2-byte words, so it contains 1 gigabyte of memory. If I have 64-bit wide data bus I can take 8 chips to have 8 gigabytes of memory in module, stacking by 4. Density is 8Gb what means 8 gigabits in each chip or 8 gigabytes in such a module.

But here comes K4AAG165WB, which have same description, but have 16Gb density. What sense does it make? If density means that chips are designed to work in 16Gb module why one can't just use first ones?

In practice I think of upgrading soldered memory in notebook and searching for proper replacement.

Comment: Looks to me like a typo in the datasheet. Somebody copy-pasted lines in the table and forgot to update the 1Gx8 and 512Mx16 cells to 2Gx8 and 1Gx16 like the bottom pair.

Comment: Yes, Samsung page for K4AAG165WB says its 1Gx16, so you are right. Thank you.